# Use of _ when invoking a method

Tags: scala

Output of below :

```
getNum(_);
  getNum(3);

  def getNum(num: Int) {
    println("Num is " + num)
  }
```

is

```
Num is 3
```

Why is `getNum(_);` not invoked ? How is `_` used in this case ?

Comment: `getNum(_)` returns a new function.  Since your code doesn't save or invoke the new function, it is thrown away.

Comment: In addition to Pedro's answer, I recommend reading http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you'd expect it to be? `getNum(null)` ?

The `getNum(_);` is translated into, something like:

```
{ x:Int => getNum(x) }
```

Which is a anonymous function and a value itself.

You could do for example:

```
val f = getNum(_)
f(42)
```

Then you'd see:

```
Num is 42
```

Comment: you would probably see `Num is 42` :D

Answer (score 1):

`_` is used to partially apply a function.  Partial application of a function produces another function with some of its parameters already applied.

```
val f = getNum(_) // partially apply
f(3) // apply the function
```